# Calling a component inside another component (React)

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm new to React and I'd like to understand how you can call a component inside another component.
I have a component folder which contains a RecipeCard.js:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Ingredients } from './Ingredients';

export class Recipe extends Component {
    render() {
      return <div class="recipecard">
          <p class="texterecipecard">
              Recette: {tartetomate.props.name}, <br/>
              Difficulté: {tartetomate.props.difficulty},<br/>
              Vous aurez besoin de {Ingredients}.<br/> {tartetomate.props.recette}
          </p>
      </div>;
      
    }
  };

  const tartetomate = <Recipe name="Tarte tomate" difficulty="Moyenne" ingredients= {Ingredients} recette="Mélanger les ingrédients dans un moule, faire cuire le tout à 190 degrés pendant 20 min." />
```

When I try to call {Ingredients} inside the render part of my Recipe component, it does not work, there are no errors with eslint but it simply does not render. It leaves a blank. {Ingredients} refers to another component in a Ingredient.js file that simply renders a paragraph.

Why does this not work and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Components vs. Elements

`Ingredients` is a **React component**, which is a JS-class or JS-function.

These are not valid as a React child, and are not rendered, plus you should get a warning in the console, like:
`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child ...`

You need to insert a **React *element*** instead of a React *component*), e.g.:

```
class Ingredients extends Component {
    render(){
        return <p>(content of Ingredients)</p>
    }
}

export class Recipe extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <p>
                Vous aurez besoin de <Ingredients />.<br/>
            </p>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

A React element is an Object, returned by e.g. `React.createElement( Ingredients )`, or by using the equivalent JSX syntax `<Ingredients />`

#### Passing props

You should not access your global `tartetomate.props` from inside `Recipe`. Instead use the `props` of Recipe to pass the values, e.g.:

```
export class Recipe extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    // assure this.props works correctly
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <p>
                Recette: { this.props.name }, <br/>
                Difficulté: { this.props.difficulty },<br/>
                Vous aurez besoin de <Ingredients/>.<br/> { this.props.recette }
            </p>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

#### Using the Component

Then you can add the `Recipe` inside another component, like:

```
export class RecipeWithValues extends Component {
    render(){
        return <Recipe
            name="Tarte tomate"
            difficulty="Moyenne"
            ingredients={ Ingredients }
            recette="Mélanger les ingrédients dans un moule, faire cuire le tout à 190 degrés pendant 20 min."
        />;
    }
}
```

#### `tartetomate`

Your `tartetomate` is a React element already, created by the JSX syntax `<Recipe ... />`, stored in the global scope. That looks like bad style, and you probably don't need it, because you can use `<Recipe ... />` directly.

But if you need it for some reason, you could use it like:

```
const tartetomate = <Recipe
    name="Tarte tomate"
    difficulty="Moyenne"
    ingredients={ Ingredients }
    recette="Mélanger les ingrédients dans un moule, faire cuire le tout à 190 degrés pendant 20 min."
/>;

export class RecipeWithValues extends Component {
    render(){
        return <div>{ tartetomate }</div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using React components like this :

```
import React from 'react';


function ComponentInside({name}) {

    return (
        <div>
            Hello, {name}
        </div>
    )
}


function Component() {
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            I'm the container

            <ComponentInside name='Paul'/>

            <ComponentInside name='Jack'/>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Component;
```

Then you can use `<Component/>` in your `App.js`